# añadir variables de sistema desde CMD

Tags: variables, cmd, batch

Estoy realizando una serie de procesos repetitivos en varios equipos que creo que se podrían solucionar preparando un pequeño batch.

El caso es que buscando por internet he encontrado lo siguiente:

```
setx TEST "C:\"
```

Lo cual crearía una variable de USUARIO llamada test con valor "C:\".

Veo que si se usa SET, la variable se crea para sistema pero es temporal, en cuanto se reinicie el equipo o se cierre la ventana de cmd, se pierde, y tampoco me resulta útil.

El caso es que las variables que necesito generar son variables de SISTEMA, no de USUARIO puesto que la aplicación que luego usará dichas variables puede ser usada por varios usuarios en el mismo equipo.

Así pues, alguien tiene idea de cómo puedo registrar estas variables de sistema de un modo simple, llámese batch o llámese cualquier otro sistema.

Comment: No lo he probado, pero en la documentación parece que si le pasas /m a setx le indicas que la variable tiene que ser del sistema: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx

Comment: ostras!! como pude no verlo en la documentación si fue lo primero que fui a revisar... estoy muy ciega.
Gracias ordago, ponlo como solución para marcarla como la solución correcta. Mil gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede llamar a setx con el argumento `/m`. Según la documentación:

> **/m**: Specifies to set the variable in the system environment. The default setting is the local environment.

Por lo que haciendo `setx /m TEST "C:\"` se establecería una variable de sistema con clave "TEST" y valor "C:\"

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx